# Can I claim my child before birth?

Tags: united-states, taxes, dependents

I have a child on the way, planning to be born around October. I heard that if the kid is born before the end of the year then you get the benefit for the whole year. Is this true?

Could I claim the kid as an allowance now and reap the benefit?

Comment: But if the unfortunate happens and the child is miscarried or stillborn, you don't get the benefit; only if the child is born alive (even if he/she later dies) do you get the benefit; so there is a risk to "counting your chickens before they hatch".

Comment: Do you mean a withholding allowance on your W-4 form?  You can claim as many as you want (say if you have a lot of itemized deductions).  The only problem is if you don't withhold enough to cover your tax bill, you might incur an underpayment penalty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under the new tax code, you do not have personal "exemptions", just an expanded child tax credit. So those with an under 17 year old child have a benefit to claim.

Yes, you can adjust allowances to account for this. In fact, you are allowed to open a 529 account as well once the pregnancy is documented. This is also part of the new tax code.